# Como deletar caracteres de uma string dentro de uma matriz em Python

Tags: python, string, matriz

Estou iniciando em python e resolvi mexer com arquivos `.txt`.
Fiz o seguinte procedimento para inserir valores em uma matriz, e a partir dela inserir cada valor em uma linha de um arquivo `filename.txt`.

```
def insertFile():
    vet = []
    for j in range(2):
        subVet = []
        for i in range(2):
            subVet.append(raw_input())
        vet.append(subVet)

    file = open("filename.txt", "w")
    file.close()

    file = open("filename.txt", "w")
    for j in range(2):
        for i in range(2):
            file.write(vet[i][j]+'\n')
    file.close()

    file = open("filename.txt", "r")
    print(file.read())
    file.close()
```

O conteúdo do `filename.txt` é o seguinte

```
1
2
3
4
```

Assim eu salvo em um documento externo os valores que utilizei, podendo acessá-los posteriormente. Para isso, fiz um outro procedimento que deveria ler o arquivo e re-inserir o conteúdo na matriz de mesmo tamanho do procedimento anterior:

```
def readFile():
    vet = []
    file = open("filename.txt", "r")
    for j in range(2):
        subVet = []
        for i in range(2):
            subVet.append(file.readline())
        vet.append(subVet)
    file.close()

    print vet
```

Tenho dois problemas aqui. O primeiro é que o conteúdo da matriz é:

```
[['1\n', '2\n'], ['3\n', '4']]
```

Note que o último elemento não tem `\n`. A ideia é que ficasse apenas:

```
[['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
```

Sem os `\n`. Tentei remover de algumas formas com split, replace mas não obtive sucesso.

O segundo seria transformá-los em inteiro, mas creio que se conseguir retirar o `\n` basta usar `int()`.

Alguém sabe como proceder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para remover o caractere `\n` da linha, basta você utilizar o método `strip`:

```
subVet.append(file.readline().strip())
```

O método `strip` retornará uma *string* removendo espaços em branco e `\n` tanto do início quanto do final da *string* original, assim, a linha `"1\n"` retornará `"1"`. Se quiser converter para inteiro, basta utilizar a função `int`:

```
subVet.append(int(file.readline().strip()))
```

Fora isso, seu código pode ser melhorado.

Pelo o que entendi do código, você está lendo uma matriz 2x2 do usuário e quer salvar em arquivo cada valor em uma linha. Para abrir o arquivo, recomendo você utilizar o gerenciador de contexto com o `with`, assim não precisa se preocupar em fechar o arquivo. Aliás, você abre o arquivo e logo o fecha na função `insertFile`. Isso não fez muito sentido e, se for apenas para limpar o conteúdo atual do arquivo, é desnecessário. Abrir o arquivo no modo `w` já faz isso. Ao meu ver, sua função `insertFile` poderia ficar assim:

```
from itertools import chain

def insert_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "w") as file:
        matrix = []
        for i in range(2):
            row = []
            for j in range(2):
                row.append(raw_input())
            matrix.append(row)
        file.write("\n".join(chain(*matrix)))
```

A função `chain` fará que uma matriz da forma `[["1", "2"], ["3", "4"]]` vire `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`. Com `"\n".join()` criamos uma *string* com os valores da lista anterior separados por um `\n`, ficando: `"1\n2\n3\n4\n"`, assim, quando escrevermos no arquivo, cada valor ficará em uma linha.

Já na leitura acredito que não tem muito o que fazer diferente do que já fez:

```
def read_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        matrix = []
        for i in range(2):
            row = []
            for j in range(2):
                row.append(int(file.readline().strip()))
            matrix.append(row)
    return matrix
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/NRm1/0) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/XOJknI)</sup>

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Funcionou direitinho :)

Comment: @EmanoelFraguas tem algumas melhorias que podem ser feitas no código. Estou elaborando na resposta...

Comment: Tudo bem, pelo o que tenho visto em outros sites tem forma mais 'limpas' de se fazer os códigos em python. Como eu vim do Pascal acabo tendo algumas manias antigas ainda. Mas creio que com prática e buscas acabo otimizando mais. Códigos estes que estão no meu GitHub (aprendi a usar recentemente haha), inclusive este dai.

Comment: @EmanoelFraguas fiz as alterações. Veja se ficou compreensível.

Comment: Realmente ficou bem melhor. Já vou procurar saber mais sobre `with/as` e `chain`. Obrigado novamente.